# Is Cassandra on the same host as a file server bad?

Tags: cassandra

I am learning about the Cassandra database and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oawc4doC76U&t=2712s) video states that "Cassandra doesn't like when there is a file server running on the same host as a Cassandra node".

Is that really true? And if yes: Why?

Comment: Can u mention the time in the video when this was discussed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable reason for this phrase is that Cassandra is IO-intensive process, and having the file server on the same node will interfere with Cassandra's reads/writes, leading to performance degradation.

This could be a less problem if you're using SSDs, and/or using different disks for Cassandra data & files served by file server.